# How does suspended user survive?

Tags: support

My friend recently got suspension for his super user account due to his fault on answering questions.

He likes to clarify the following

If a user gets their account suspended, they cannot answer questions,post comments. So obviously he/she cant earn reputations back.

The user will be at 1 reputation. So how does does the community give the user chance to prove themselves again within the suspended period?

Comment: He cannot participate during the suspension period. That's the whole point. The reputation and related privileges will be returned after the suspension ends. This is different from being banned from only e.g. posting questions, or answers.

Comment: @DanielBeck sir so what can he do if he/she likes to answer some question wish to ask a question (or) answer a question as he can't answer a question which he/she already if he/she faced in a reallfe situation atleast why can't the community can give him to provide comments on answers/questions?

Comment: @vikki The best thing would be not getting suspended in the first place. Once suspended, it is usually too late to do anything but wait for it to end. Suspension is a rather harsh punishment only used for particularly bad or repeated infringements.

Comment: [Suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(punishment))

Comment: @bob i agree with the first thing as maybe due to his repeated errors,how does this community provides him/her to survive in superuser during the suspended period ?what were the things provided to him/her to prove themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The user will be at 1 reputation. So how does does the community give the user chance to prove themselves again within the suspended period?

The whole point of being suspended is

- Take a break from the system
- Read, understand **why** the person was suspended
- Follow up on tips mentioned on how the person should do after getting unsuspended.

The reputation levels will be restored after the suspension ends. The way to approach suspension is to accept and improve upon things highlighted, **not** to get around suspension. If the user needs any "doubts" to be clarified, the user can reply back to the Mod message which is issued when a suspension is put in place.

There's nothing to prove **during** the suspension period, only after the suspension period is up.

Comment: what can he/she do if he/she has an bounty question he can't award bounty withing his/her suspension period

Comment: @vikki bounty will be auto allocated provided the auto-allocation conditions are met.

Comment: sir please  provide the auto allocation conditions link ,since i am unaware of it

Comment: @vikki [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

Answer (score 0):

> So how does does the community give the user chance to prove themselves again within the suspended period?

You don't need to do proof anything. That would defeat the purpose of a suspension...

There are only two things you can do:

1. Learn why you have been suspended in the first place, and never break the rules again.
2. Wait until the suspension is over.

That's real life. There are no out-of-jail cards...

Comment: i agree with you,but how can the particular user can clarify his/her doubts during the suspension period as he cant even participate in meta to tell his/her opinion?

Comment: `You don't need to do proof anything.`

Comment: i agree that he don't need to proof anything,why can't this community provide him/her an opportunity to ask a question in superuser as this site is to guide the user's to clarify their doubts!

Comment: Why does it have to? If you get suspended you know what you've done wrong.